# Is it safe to emit signal passing QObject pointer as parameter right before the passed object is going to be destroyed?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Lets consider this simple example:

```
Class Emitter: public QObject {
...
signal:
    surfaceDestroyed(QObject*);
public:
    void emittingMethod(QObject* surface) {
        emit surfaceDestroyed(surface);
        delete surface;
    }
}
```

I have a queued connection for this case

```
connect(emitterObject, SIGNAL(surfaceDestroyed(QObject*), receiverObject,
    SLOT(onSurfaceDestroyed(QObject*)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

In onSurfaceDestroyed method the received QObject is dereferenced and used

So the question is how safe this code is? I've read pretty much info on that on QT site and here, but I still don't have a clear understanding of the problem.

In my opinion this code is not safe, as a signal can be sent, then surface destroyed, than when an event comes for receiverObject once the event loop is processed and receiver object accesses released memory, thus SIGSEGV

This is a simplified example of real code, so it's hard to track if crashes can happen because of that.

Comment: I think calling `surface->deleteLater();` would be even safer.

Comment: Well, as a rule of thumb, if it feels bad, don't. :-)  Would it not be better to have the destroyed object's destructor do whatever it is you want done?

Comment: @vahancho yes, I wanted to mention about deleteLater on the question but finally it slipped my mind. It generally should be safer, but I would like to be 100% sure if this code can or cannot crash.

Comment: Why can't you rewrite your signals/slots to not pass an object you are going to delete imminently ? Why not emit `aboutToDestroy(QObject*)` to tell the other object to consider it deleted ?

Comment: @WesMiller Yes you are right, but as I mentioned the real code is much   more complicated, so I can't do everything easy

Comment: @rightaway717, to make it absolutely safe, you might consider changing the design, btw. For example, use const references instead of pointers, or leave deletion of the `surface` object on to the component that has created it. Where this `surface` comes from?

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184209 One solution to this issue would be shared pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the type of the signal-slot connection. Connections are *direct* by default if the sender and the receiver belong to the same thread. In this case the slot will be called immediately when you emit the signal. When the signal function is finished, you can be sure that the slot has also finished.

When the sender and the receiver belong to different threads, the connection is *queued* by default. In this case your code is not safe. The slot can be called much later than the signal was called. Even `deleteLater` will not save the situation because it's processed by the sender's thread's event loop and doesn't depend on the other thread's event loop.

So if you want to write such code, ensure that your objects are in the same thread. You can pass `Qt::DirectConnection` option to `connect` function to make connection type more clear.

If you want to use queued connection, you can emit e.g. `aboutToBeDeleted` signal in the sender. The receiver will receive that signal, process it somehow and respond with `cleanUpCompleted` signal that will trigger the actual object deletion.

Also consider using standard `QObject::destroyed` signal. It's called immediately before the object is destroyed but can be useful in many cases.

Comment: @vahancho I don't think I can still use QObject, that emitted destroyed() signal to access that object's members etc, as at the time I received it, all destructors of derived classes from QObject has already done their job, right? destroyed() signal is emitted right from dtor of QObject.

Comment: @rightaway717 You can use the `destroyed()` signal to access the object it sends as a parameter, if you are using a direct connection. If you are using a queued connection, then the object will be destroyed before your slot gets called.

Comment: @thuga surface in my case is an object of derived class from QObject, lets call this class Surface. QObject dtor is not trivial, so ~Surface is considered not trivial either anyways. As per c++ standard dereferencing a pointer of an object, whose non-trivial destructor was called is UB. Thus as I think even if I have a direct connection, this is still UB. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @rightaway717 Yes, casting the `QObject` pointer to your own object type would fail.You could only work with the `QObject` members.