# Is it safe to call deleteLater right after emitting a signal with the object?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I believe the following code is safe, but I have not been able to confirm it:

```
void someMethod(Process *process) {
    emit signalWithProcess(process);
    process->deleteLater();
}
```

I'm not sure if `process` still exists when the signals are called and auto or queued connections are used.

For direct connections, the code above is correct because the slots are called synchronously. AFAIK, for slots on the same thread as the object, it is also correct because `deleteLater()` posts a new event to the object's event loop. However, the signal events are posted earlier so they run earlier.

However, for queued connections on **different** threads I do not understand how it works and whether the code above is safe. My gut-feeling says yes, but I have not been able to verify it.

---

For example, the process object above belongs to thread **A** and there's a queued connection to another object on thread **B**. When `someMethod()` runs, it adds the queued signals to thread **B**'s event loop and adds the `deleteLater` event to thread **A**'s event loop.

Unless there is some way to block thread **A** from deleting the object while the slot is run in thread **B**, this seems not to be safe. Unfortunately, I have not found anything related to that in the source code or the documentation.

---

Similar question (but without `deleteLater`): [Is it safe to emit signal passing QObject pointer as parameter right before the passed object is going to be destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376571)

Comment: This does not look safe to me. In theory, thread B could receive the `signalWithProcess` signal, and in the middle of its handling of it, thread A runs again and deletes `process`.

Comment: I might suggest a QSharedPointer or something similar.

Comment: @JarMan I think you might be right, but that would mean that signals with pointers to QObjects are **never** safe because the slot in thread **B** might be delayed for a very long time.

Comment: The same argument could be said of any function. They are not inherently thread-safe unless you make them so. The other question that you link to has this line in the accepted answer: *"Even deleteLater will not save the situation because it's processed by the sender's thread's event loop and doesn't depend on the other thread's event loop."* That pretty directly answers your question.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks, I didn't see that part when I read the question. Assuming it is correct, this answers it. So the rule should be: do not use raw pointers for signal&slots across threads unless you have a way to synchronize the lifetime data, for example with smart pointers.